# how to get binary format values from video file?

Tags: java, android, web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert video file(.mp4) format into binary format in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427997/how-to-convert-video-file-mp4-format-into-binary-format-in-android)

I have one video(.MP4)file. i want to know video file binary value to upload the video in web server..Any one knows tell me am waiting thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "video file binary value" precisely? If you just mean the file contents, you'd just read the binary data using `FileInputStream`. The fact that it's a video is irrelevant.

Comment: i want to upload a video in web server.. if i want to upload a video in web server means i want to pass a request as binary value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416562/how-to-convert-video-file-mp4-3gp-format-into-binary-format-in-android/13416628#13416628 Same Question

Comment: i cant convert with help of that code..

Comment: strAttachmentCoded = new String(byteBinaryData);                         tell me use of this code